# How to create an Azure DevOps Organization programmatically

Tags: azure-devops, azure-cli

I have the need to be able to create completely new Azure DevOps organizations from scratch. I have tried with azure devops cli but there just seems to be no way to do it.

I already checked MS documentation but it only mentions the manual way through a browser to do so.

Is this even possible?

Comment: Why are you creating so many organizations that you need to automate it? That sounds like a misunderstanding of the purpose and scope of an organization.

Comment: I understand that, and it is for different customers so they cannot interact with each other. These customers are all quite small and each of them want to benefit that the first 5 users per organization are free. That way, each of them can start small and grow when needed.

Comment: You used to be able to create organization through the Azure Portal and an ARM template. It's been a while since I tried. https://github.com/Microsoft/devops-project-samples/blob/master/armtemplates/devopsproject/template.json

Comment: but those would be tied to the same Azure Bill, I would imagine

Comment: Yes indeed, I'd rather see a completely independent organization. I guess it's up to manual.

Comment: @DanielMann - (hey, its been a while)... Organizations can be transferred.. So if I am working with you, I can create an organization, and when I am done transfer it in its entirety with full fidelity to you.  Can't do that at the project level....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *Is this even possible?*

As far as I know it is not possible to create organizations in Azure DevOps programmatically. You can create [Projects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/core/projects/create?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1), [Work Items](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20items/create?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) or [Teams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/core/teams/create?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) through [Rest API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) but not Organizations.

In addition, please also refer to [Use Azure DevOps REST API to Delete organizations / accounts?](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/vsts-rest-api-specs/issues/167) Where you can see there isn't a way to automate delete an organization currently too.

Comment: It was possible to create from az CLI using a deployment template or type `microsoft.visualstudio/account` but it seems they've closed that option now. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63891559/create-an-azure-devops-organization-through-azure-cli