# Create an Azure DevOps organization through Azure CLI

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-cli

I want to create a new Azure DevOps organization with the az command line.

I have installed the devops extension.

I have read the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/create-organization?view=azure-devops) and it describes how to create an organization through web interface, but there is nothing described for command line.

I have also read the documentation of [az](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/reference-index?view=azure-cli-latest) and [az devops](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/devops?view=azure-cli-latest) extension.

Have I missed something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am afraid currently it is not supported to create Azure DevOps organization via az devops command line or the DevOps REST API.

However, you can use Azure CLI [az resource create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/resource?view=azure-cli-latest#az_resource_create) to create a resource of type `microsoft.visualstudio/account` as a workaround. This will create an Azure DevOps organization. For example:

```
az resource create -g AzureResourceGroup -n MyDevopsOrganizationName `
    --resource-type microsoft.visualstudio/account --is-full-object `
    --properties '{\"location\":\"Central Us\", \"properties\":{ \"operationType\": \"Create\"}}'
```

The command above creates Azure DevOps organization MyDevopsOrganizationName.
`https://MyDevopsOrganizationName.visualstudio.com`

You can also [use an ARM template to create an Azure DevOps organization](https://github.com/microsoft/devops-project-samples/blob/master/armtemplates/devopsproject/template.json).

Comment: Thanks. I have the same problem to add an ssh key on dev.azure.com. Is there a way to do this ?

Comment: I am afraid it cannot be done to add an ssh via command line/rest api.  You can go and vote it up on [this user voice](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/1126491/upload-public-ssh-key-to-user-setting-through-rest.html)